# Probability - Continuous Joint Probability

Tags: probability

I am taking a probability class and I am not sure how to solve this problem:

> Suppose $Z=X+Y$, find $f_Z$ if
> $$
>  f_X(x)=f_Y(x)=
> \begin{cases}
> x/2, \text{ when }0<x<2 \\ 0, \text{ otherwise}
> \end{cases}
> $$

I know the solution is $f_Z=x^3/24$ when 0<x<2 and $f_Z=x-x^3/24-4/3$ when 2<x<4

I understand that f(x,y)=xy/4 when 0<x,y<2

I am looking for a simplified answer to get to the bottom line of the concept. Is the Jacobian matrix necessary for this? The limits of integration have always been challenging when doing these problems. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to assume independence between X and Y.

Then, the Jacobian method is not the only one possible but it is a good choice (IMHO)

Setting

$$
\begin{cases}
u=x+y, \\
v=x,
\end{cases}\rightarrow \begin{cases}
x=v, \\
y=u-v,
\end{cases}$$

The jacobian is 1 and the joint density of $(U;V)$ is the following

$$f_{UV}(u,v)=\frac{v(u-v)}{4}$$

defined in the following parallelogram

[image]

Do you think you are able to integrate $f(u,v)$ over $V$-support to obtain the marginal $f_U(u)$?

Comment: Thanks a lot! I really appreciate it. So you integrate between 0 and u when 0<u<2, right? What are the limits of integration for 2<u<4? Is it u-2 to 4? Also, what would happen if the Jacobian was, let's say, 2? Would you multiply 2 by f(u,v)?

Comment: @123 : 1)  yes; 2) no, integrate from (u-2) to 2. 3) yes. Since you're new here, I would like to encourage you to click the check mark if this answer was helpful for you. It'll encourage others to answer your questions in the future